# What does Faramir mean by "divers characters"?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-two-towers

When Faramir is describing the archives of Gondor he states:

> We in the house of Denethor know much ancient lore by long tradition, and there are moreover in our treasuries many things preserved: books and tablets writ on withered parchments, yea, and on stone, and on leaves of silver and of gold, in divers characters.

My son asked what "divers characters" are and I have no idea.  Google doesn't seem much help at the moment.

Comment: This is really a question for one of the English Language Stack Exchange sites. "Divers" is an archaic spelling of "diverse" - ie, the writings are in multiple different scripts or alphabets/writing systems. See Merriam-Webster: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/divers

Comment: Just for your curiosity: D'ivers are a kind a shapeshifters in the "Malazan Book of the Fallen Series". They are a pretty cool devious invention there. https://malazan.fandom.com/wiki/D%27ivers

Comment: @MattGutting - More likely [english.se] rather than [ell.se], but I suspect that both would close it with "Did you do your homework [research] before coming here?"

Comment: @MattGutting I'm aware this has had no close votes or flags as far as I can tell so far but in case anyone is going to it is worth noting that there is nothing wrong with these questions being asked here on SFF, see [this meta post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11626/58193), for example.

Comment: Characters who explore the ocean, of course!

Comment: The more you read Lord of the Rings, di verse it gets 

Comment: @PaulD.Waite ohh, that one’s bad :D

Comment: Terry Pratchett wrote about "divers alarums and excursions" in Wyrd Sisters. Of course, this being Pratchett, his characters muse that the excursions are probably on the seaside, where "the divers can recover from all them alarums"...

Comment: @thelethalcarrot thanks! I didn't realize that one. I think this is a case where I'd disagree with the general Meta answer, though.

Comment: @MattGutting Note that "divers" and "diverse" are _different words_, not just variant spellings; to my knowledge, "divers" is always a qualifier, whereas "diverse" is a generic adjective.

Comment: @chrylis I don't think I follow you. Unless you mean that "diverse" can be used as a predicate adjective,and modified by "very" and so on, and "divers" can't? That would be a good question for English Language and Usage.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

> **books and tablets writ on withered parchments**, yea, and on stone, and on leaves of silver and of gold, in divers characters.

Let me de-archaic this for you:

> The books and [plaques written] on [old paper<sup>1</sup>], [yes], and [also] on stone, and [written on sheets] of silver and of gold, [written] in [diverse<sup>2</sup>] characters [from many languages and writing systems].

Tolkien is being florid in having Faramir say "Gosh! There were so many different documents in so  many languages!"

<sup>1</sup> "Parchment" is made from animal skin.

<sup>2</sup> "Divers" is from Old French for "different, odd, wicked, cruel," and in 18th century English is recorded as meaning "different, or not alike in character; not of the same kind" "now expressed by **diverse**."—Oxford English Dictionary 2nd Ed.

Comment: [Parchment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parchment) isn't paper. It's animal skin.

Comment: @PM2Ring It sure is! (Except no: it is actually made from *processed* animal skin.) And we totally don't use that widely for writing in the time in which this question was asked and in which I wrote my answer. ;)

Comment: Ah, it makes perfect sense once I see it.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "old french" (used in old french or appeared first in old french ?), but just as an information, this word is still common :)

Comment: "Character" sometimes means handwriting rather than glyphs of a writing system. Therefore it is possible that rather than "diverse writing systems", Tolkien meant "diverse handwriting". I.e., even though everybody was writing in e.g. Feanorian script, it is clear that several different people were writing.

Comment: @FlorianCastelain That means when the word entered English it was borrowed from old French, which gives us an approximate time for when it entered English.

Comment: Faramir is a learned man for his time and speaks as a scholar about scholarly things. In Appendix F, in the section "Of Men," Tolkien says, "... in Gondor whence it came the Westron [the Common Speech] kept still a more gracious and antique style." The speech of the hobbits is less fancy, and this is clearly intentional.

Comment: +1 @RossPresser That is a fair read! I am slightly inclined against that interpretation, because I think Tolkien would have had Faramir expressed such as "divers character" singular (since styles of handwriting, like water, are uncountable). But that's more my inclination than a massif of reasoning. :)

Comment: @FlorianCastelain Todd Wilcox has nailed it: "from old French" indicates route through which "divers" entered the English language.

Answer (score 35):

### different writing systems

In Hammond and Scull's *The Lord of the Rings, A Reader's Companion* (pg 471), this line is explained as meaning "in many different (diverse) writing systems".

> **670 (II: 278). in divers characters** - In many different (diverse) writing systems.

Comment: +1 for referencing the Reader's Companion, which can be helpful in many other instances.

Comment: @MatthieuM. - Generally any "what does this part of LotR mean?" questions can be answered with the reader's companion.

Answer (score 1):

### Various scripts and languages

"Divers" is an old spelling/synonym of "Diverse." As such, a more modern form of that passage would be:

> We in the house of Denethor have a lot of ancient knowledge, and we have a lot of rare books in our treasuries: books and tablets written on ancient parchment, on stone, and on tablets made from silver and gold, in a bunch of different languages.